# Как открыть файл с названием на русском языке?

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Насколько я знаю их никак не открыть, потому что fopen() принимает тип const char*, однако должен же быть какой то выход. Мне нужно считывать посимвольно и поэтому я столкнулась с этим

MinGW

Comment: Какой у вас компилятор? Не MinGW случайно?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да именно он. Он не открывает априори?

Comment: Если передавать путь в кодировке utf-8, то все открывается... Я на си как-то это делаю же.

Comment: @こきん Тоже MinGW? Откуда качали? У меня не открывалось, когда последний раз пробовал.

Comment: @こきん Сходил проверил - MinGW из MSYS2 ожидает там какую-то другую кодировку, явно не UTF-8.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ой, у меня не utf-8, но если и так, то 現在のコード ページ: 932

Comment: Проверьте, что вы передаете в `fopen()` строку в кодировке **cp1251**

Comment: @avp как это сделать, до этого с кодировкой не сталкивалась

Comment: спасибо @avp вы правы, я разобралась fopen( utf8_to_win1251(name).c_str() , "r"); где inline std::string utf8_to_win1251( const QString & str ) {
    QTextCodec * codec = QTextCodec::codecForName( "Windows-1251" );
    if ( ! codec )
    {
        return std::string();
    }
    return codec->fromUnicode( str ).toStdString();
}

Comment: Если научились конвертить между кодировками, то лучше сконвертить в UTF-16 и звать `_wfopen`. Вряд ли `fopen` всегда использует win-1251, скорее кодировка зависит от настроек языка в системе.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже с этим столкнулся.

**Вариант 1**, мой любимый: Конвертировать путь в UTF-16 и использовать `_wfopen`.

Вот пример обертки над `fopen`/`_wfopen`, которая сама это делает:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <filesystem>

// Like regular fopen, but can handle unicode paths on MinGW.
[[nodiscard]] inline FILE *better_fopen(const char *name, const char *mode)
{
    #ifndef __MINGW32__
    return std::fopen(name, mode);
    #else
    constexpr int max_mode_len = 3;
    wchar_t wide_mode[max_mode_len + 1]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < max_mode_len; i++)
    {
        wide_mode[i] = mode[i];
        if (mode[i] == '\0')
            break;
    }
    return _wfopen(std::filesystem::u8path(name).c_str(), wide_mode); // In C++20 `u8path` will be deprecated in favor of a new constructor.
    #endif
}
```

**Вариант 2**: В MSYS2 есть новый (экспериментальный?) вариант MinGW, они называют его `UCRT64`. Он использует в качестве стандартой библиотеки C `ucrtbase.dll` вместо древней `msvcrt.dll`, и, *насколько я слышал*, поддерживает юникодные пути из коробки.

Минус - собранные им программы не работают из коробки на Windows 7, если руками не поставить эту самую `ucrtbase.dll`.

**Вариант 3**: Перелезть на `std::ifstream`, и передавать ему путь в виде `std::filesystem::path`.

Comment: не поняла, Вы открывали для чтения и записи? почему массив из 3 элементов

Comment: @kaliarty Какой режим передадите вторым параметром, так и откроется. Смысл параметра тот же, что у простого `fopen`. *"почему массив из 3 элементов"* Во-первых размер - 4, а не 3. Максимальная длина второго параметра, насколько я знаю, 3 (+1 нулевой байт в конце), например `"w+b"`.

Comment: @kaliarty Разобрались?

Comment: у меня выдает ошибку  no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>::basic_string(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/experimental/filesystem:39:0,
Без nclude <experimental/filesystem> не компилируется

Comment: @kaliarty У вас GCC старый, 7.3. Поставьте 10 или 11. Лучше всего установить его из MSYS2.

Comment: тогда мне не годиться это решение. С новой сборкой не работает библиотека (не могу её выкинуть, этот проект делает еще один человек)

Comment: @kaliarty Какая конкретно библиотека, и как именно не работает? И почему тот человек тоже не может обновиться?

Comment: Вообще, на старом GCC решение - вручную преобразовывать UTF-8 в UTF-16. Но лучше обновиться.

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_and_LaTeX_via_KLFBackend, для отрисовки latex, ничего другого не нашла

Comment: @kaliarty Так, а как именно она не работает на новом ГЦЦ?

Comment: она не совместила совсем как я поняла, проекты не собираются

Comment: @kaliarty Лучше отдельный вопрос напишите, и расскажите подробно, что там не совместимо, какие ошибки при компиляции, и т. п.

Comment: @kaliarty За полчаса скомпилировал этот klatexformula, запустил демку. Формулу правда нарисовать не смог, надо с настройками разбираться. Но вполне компилируется, всего пару строчек понадобилось поправить.